# How to remove org.apache.maven.plugin.jar.JarMojo error from pom editor

Tags: java, spring, maven, pom.xml

I am using Spring Tool Suite 3.1.0.RELEASE and the pom.xml file in every project that I create has a single error entitled "org.apache.maven.plugin.jar.JarMojo". No further error details.

This error is present even in the auto generated pom.xml when creating a new Spring Utility Project.

It does not cause any errors during build, it is only shown in the IDE (top of the Overview tab in the pom editor and first line of pom.xml).

[image: org.apache.maven.plugin.jar.JarMojo error screenshot]

Anyone seen this before and knows how to fix it? Google has not been helpful.

Here is the default pom.xml generated by my Spring Tool Suite for a Spring Utility Project (it causes the error described):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.springframework.samples.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-utility</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Spring Utility</name>
    <url>http://www.springframework.org</url>
    <description>
        <![CDATA[
      This project is a minimal jar utility with Spring configuration.
    ]]>
    </description>
    <properties>
        <maven.test.failure.ignore>true</maven.test.failure.ignore>
        <spring.framework.version>3.0.6.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
    </properties>   <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.14</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build> 
</project>
```

Comment: Please provide your pom.

Comment: Sorry, probably a good idea. Added now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed. I downloaded Maven 3.0.5 separately and extracted to C:\springsource\apache-maven-3.0.5. (STS was using Maven 3.0.3) Then in STS went to Windows->Preferences from the menu, searched for "installations" to find the Maven installations page. Added a new installation by pointing to the folder above. Applied. Then right clicked on existing project and chose Maven->Update Project. Error gone.

All new projects also don't have the error anymore. Win.

Answer (score 2):

We faced the same issue with Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers (Juno Service Release 2), POM.xml simply has this "org.apache.maven.plugin.jar.JarMojo" error as shown in the above diagram.

This seems a version issue with newer Maven. Finally we install an older C:\apache-maven-3.0.5

Then inside Eclipse -> Windows -> Preference -> search "Maven" -> Installations, add the External C:\apache-maven-3.0.5

[image: reference to external Maven 3.0.5]

Then go Project -> Clean
and right click on existing proect -> Maven -> Update Projects
and maybe restart EClipse.

The error status will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

convert the packaging from jar to war. This solved my problem.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Perhaps you can add more details, to explain better the most important parts of your answer. Have a read of [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more information. Also, once you get more reputation, you will be able to post this as a comment rather than an answer, which would be more appropriate.

Comment: You Should be Descriptive with your Answer .