# Eclipse Maven Error: org.apache.maven.plugin.jar.JarMojo error from pom editor

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

I am trying to create a new Maven project from eclipse. I end up with this error in my pom.xml.

```
org.apache.maven.plugin.jar.JarMojo
```

I have tried to look everywhere. I found a stackoverflow question [How to remove org.apache.maven.plugin.jar.JarMojo error from pom editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767631/how-to-remove-org-apache-maven-plugin-jar-jarmojo-error-from-pom-editor)
But i was not able to get rid of this error.

Can anyone please help me with this?

I am really sorry if I am asking something silly. But I am completely stuck. May be I am missing something. 
I am using Maven 3.0.5

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>123</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>test name</name>
  <description>test desc</description>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>C:\harish\RestApi\spring-jersey\test\src\main\java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>C:\harish\RestApi\spring-jersey\test\src\main\scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>C:\harish\RestApi\spring-jersey\test\src\test\java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>C:\harish\RestApi\spring-jersey\test\target\classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>C:\harish\RestApi\spring-jersey\test\target\test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>C:\harish\RestApi\spring-jersey\test\src\main\resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>C:\harish\RestApi\spring-jersey\test\src\test\resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <directory>C:\harish\RestApi\spring-jersey\test\target</directory>
    <finalName>test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-clean</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-install</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>install</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>resources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testResources</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testResources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-site</id>
            <phase>site</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>site</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>C:\harish\RestApi\spring-jersey\test\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>site-deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>C:\harish\RestApi\spring-jersey\test\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>C:\harish\RestApi\spring-jersey\test\target\site</outputDirectory>
          <reportPlugins>
            <reportPlugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            </reportPlugin>
          </reportPlugins>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
    <outputDirectory>C:\harish\RestApi\spring-jersey\test\target\site</outputDirectory>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

Update:
I re-did the maven installation. I am not getting this exception. 
I think there was something wrong in the version of maven used by eclipse and the one i downloaded.
i will mark this as a duplicate of [How to remove org.apache.maven.plugin.jar.JarMojo error from pom editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767631/how-to-remove-org-apache-maven-plugin-jar-jarmojo-error-from-pom-editor)

Comment: what is the exact error message ?

Comment: there is no  error message. But this message shoes up in RED "org.apache.maven.plugin.jar.JarMojo".
the screen shot is also shared in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767631/how-to-remove-org-apache-maven-plugin-jar-jarmojo-error-from-pom-editor

Answer (score 4):

Delete all over [user dir]/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven  and clean your projects.